# How to replace the originStation and destinationStation in Journey Table with the station-id from a different table i,e Station Table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

There are two table "Journey" and "Station".
Journey table consist of journey-id, originStation and destinationStation.
Station table consist of station-id, stationName.

Journey table

| id | originStation | destinationStation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Delhi | Mumbai |

Station Table

| station_id | stationName |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | Delhi |
| a2 | Mumbai |

Resulting table must be following using SQL. Thank you for helping me out.

| id | originStation | destinationStation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | a2 |

Tried the following Query but it replaces both destinationStation and originStation with same station_id

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
/* Create Table Journey */
CREATE TABLE journey(id integer PRIMARY KEY, originStation text,destinationStation text);
INSERT INTO journey VALUES(1,'Delhi', 'Mumbai');

/* Create Table Station */

CREATE TABLE station(station_id text PRIMARY KEY, stationName text);
INSERT INTO station VALUES('a1','Delhi');
INSERT INTO station VALUES('a2','Mumbai');

COMMIT;
/* Query*/
SELECT journey.id, station.station_id as originStation, station.station_id as destinationStation
        FROM journey  JOIN station
          ON journey.destinationstation = station.stationName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just `join` twice:

```
select j.*, so.stationId as originStationId, sd.stationId as destinationStationId
from journey j left join
     stations so
     on j.originStation = so.stationName left join
     stations sd
     on j.destinationStation = sd.stationName;
```